# Docker entrypoint file "no such file or directory"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a container using a docker image as part of a project that works fine on my other Windows machine (and a few other developers' machines). When upping the project on my secondary Windows machine however the entrypoint file is reported as not found

```
$ docker-compose logs -f php
Attaching to project-name-php-1
project-name-php-1 | exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint: no such file or directory
```

I've confirmed the syntax in the Dockerfile as I had seen comments from people who had used single quotes incorrectly (not that I would expect such an error given it works fine on other machines)

```
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint"]
```

I have also confirmed that file does actually exist within the image

```
docker run -it --rm --entrypoint bash theimage/inuse:thetag
root@209618ad969c:/var/www# ls -l /usr/local/bin
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      924 Jul 22 12:04 docker-entrypoint
```

The file isn't set in the container via volume mount or anything I can see, so I am out of ideas as to why the file is not found when permissions etc look correct to me.

---

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/docker/library/php:8.1-fpm-buster as cli

COPY --from=composer-base /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y git gnupg wget libzip-dev unzip libcurl4-openssl-dev pkg-config libssl-dev \
    && pecl channel-update pecl.php.net \
    && pecl install mongodb-1.16.1 \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql zip

ADD .docker/php/custom.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d

FROM composer-base as composer

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/tmp/cache,sharing=locked \
    --mount=type=bind,source=composer.json,target=/app/composer.json \
    --mount=type=bind,source=composer.lock,target=/app/composer.lock \
    composer install --no-dev --no-autoloader \
        --no-interaction --no-progress --no-scripts --no-plugins --no-ansi

FROM cli as prod

RUN rm -rf /var/www/html && \
    chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www

COPY bin /var/www/bin
COPY .docker/php/docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint && \
    chmod +x /var/www/bin/notify.sh

COPY --from=composer --chown=www-data:www-data /app/vendor/ /var/www/vendor/

COPY --chown=www-data:www-data config /var/www/config
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data data /var/www/data
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data public /var/www/public
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data src /var/www/src
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data templates /var/www/templates
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data .env /var/www/

RUN --mount=type=bind,source=/usr/bin/composer,target=/usr/local/bin/composer,from=composer \
    --mount=type=bind,source=composer.json,target=/var/www/composer.json \
    composer --working-dir=/var/www dump-autoload --optimize --no-dev \
        --no-plugins --no-scripts --no-ansi && \
    chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/vendor

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/var/cache /var/www/var/log && \
    chmod -R a+r,u+w /var/www/var && \
    chmod a+x /var/www/var/log /var/www/var/cache && \
    chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/var

ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint"]
CMD ["php-fpm"]

WORKDIR /var/www
```

**Entrypoint**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

echo "Waiting for db to be ready..."
until bin/console doctrine:database:create --if-not-exists > /dev/null 2>&1; do
  sleep 1
done

if [ "$MODE" = "PROD" ]; then
  migration=$(/var/www/bin/console doctrine:migrations:list)

  if [[ $migration =~ .*"not migrated".* ]]; then
    echo "Migration has not run. Please ensure the migration has been run before attempting to start again!"
    exit 1
  fi
else
  bin/console doctrine:migrations:sync-metadata-storage --no-interaction
  bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --no-interaction
fi

exec docker-php-entrypoint "$@"
```

---

**Entrypoint od Output**

```
0000000   #   !   /   b   i   n   /   s   h  \n   s   e   t       -   e
0000020  \n  \n   i   f       [       "   $   M   O   D   E   "       !
0000040   =       "   D   E   V   "       ]   ;       t   h   e   n  \n
0000060           i   f       [       -   f       "   /   v   a   r   /
0000100   w   w   w   /   .   e   n   v   "       ]   ;       t   h   e
0000120   n  \n                   A   P   P   _   E   N   V   =   p   r
0000140   o   d       A   P   P   _   D   E   B   U   G   =   0       p
0000160   h   p       b   i   n   /   c   o   n   s   o   l   e       d
0000200   o   t   e   n   v   :   d   u   m   p  \n                   r
0000220   m       /   v   a   r   /   w   w   w   /   .   e   n   v  \n
```

Comment: "No such file or directory" doesn't have anything to do with permissions. If `/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint` is a shell script, what interpreter does it specify in the `#!` line? Does that interpreter exist in the image?

Comment: /bin/bash, and yes it does exist in the image

Comment: Can you share the Dockerfile and entrypoint script with us?

Comment: Sure, I've added them as is

Comment: You may have DOS line endings in your entrypoint script. Can you run `docker run -it theimage/inuse:thetag bash -c 'od -c /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint | head'` and attach the output to the question? I am particularly looking for whether the output of that command has any `\r` characters.

Comment: I've attached, I see no \r characters present in the whole file

Comment: If I simplify this down to [something I can actually build](https://gist.github.com/larsks/1f37861586940e0729c6dd25e7099df6) it works without any errors. We can provide better help if you update this question to include a [mcve] -- a Dockerfile and any required support files that we can build locally to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I appreciate that, I'll see what I can put together. I'm still assuming it's outside of the project itself given this exact same code state starts up fine on my other Windows machine.

Comment: Okay I managed to figure it out by stripping my own files down and building them back up again in pieces, I believe my IDE kept butchering line endings despite the resulting file seeming fine within the built image. Forcing the IDE to use unix line endings and saving the affected files has resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end my IDE (PHPStorm) was set to system dependent line endings, and was inserting Windows endings (`\r\n`) instead of unix line endings (`\n`), despite the file within the image seeming not to have the resulting issue.

Changing the setting and saving the affected files resulted in the entrypoint functioning correctly.